# How can I delete all the duplicate rows exept one with maximum value?

Tags: android, sqlite

### id         name         exp

test01       park         500

test01       park         700

test01       park         3000

test01       park         1500

test02       kim          700

test02       kim          500

test03       lee          500

---

I want to delete all the duplicate rows except one with maximum exp value. I want to get the result like this:

---

### id           name         exp

test01        park         3000

test02        kim          700

test03        lee          500

---

I tried some sql statements but failed. Is it possible to implement what I want with one sql statement? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: are you using a list view to show the data?

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried some sql statments, but I got wrong results.

Comment: so you can get the data into a string and then delete from a string. easy approach

Answer (score 2):

Why delete? Just show only appropriate ones using query like this:

```
select id, name, max(exp) from mytable
```

**Update:** oops.. try this one:

```
select id, name, max(exp) from mytable group by id, name
```

It doesn't matter Android or not. For Android you can use: `execSQL(String sql)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. "select _id, id, name, pass, max(exp) as exp from test_table";    It gave me wrong result: Test02 kim 700.

Comment: It is android project.

Comment: You can not use execSQL with select statement. Instead, you should use query or rawQuery. I tired your code. I got some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
  WHERE ROWID NOT IN ( SELECT t1.ROWID
                        FROM  mytable AS t1,
                              (SELECT id, name, MAX(exp) AS x FROM mytable GROUP BY id, name) AS t2
                          WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.exp = t2.x
                    );
```

Comment: It gave me wrong result: Test01 park 500   Test02 kim 700 test03 lee 1000. It is different from what I expected. It is android project.

Comment: I see the correct answer in the link. But I can not get that result in android. Have you tried on android app?